# Java "multiple inheritance" using interfaces - avoid only public methods

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

My goal is a somewhat diamond-like inheritance in Java. Like this:

[image]

And I know, real multiple inheritance in Java is not possible. This is not my actual problem.

The solution everyone mentions is to use interfaces. That works and I could do that, however this inheritance is going to be part of an API. Therefore not everything should be public and accessible from the outside. But guess what: Everything in interfaces has to be public.

If you take a look at the graph again, this describes my problem further: I want to declare a method in B that gets implemented in A. However, from outside of this diamond you should not be able to access this method. My interface B needs data in a default-implemented method that it can only get from this method that A has to implement. However, from outside you should not be able to call it.

And I also know that many people say that interfaces should only specify the behavior. With my default-implemented method I somewhat break this convention. I could imagine that this is the reason why I stumble over such issues in the first place.

Now to my question: Is there a fundamental structural mistake I make? If so, which and how could I avoid it? Are there other ways to achieve such functionality?

Have a great day :)

Comment: "*Is there a fundamental structural mistake I make?*" - Depends on the code and the concrete use case; we'd need to review the code. But we do not do code revniews here, this would be more suitable for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: One possibility is to keep the inheritance and the classes private.  If the classes and methods are private, no one but you can access them.  This might be different that you were thinking, but it might be worth considering if you really need non-public behavior.

Comment: @markspace you don't appear to understand the problem here. methods in interfaces are public. Period. Even package-private interfaces. If you `implements` them, then __those methods must be `public`__. Your advice is the equivalent of telling someone asking how to get through a solid wall 'just walk through it'.

Comment: Please make your question more explicit by showing (partial) Java declarations for A, B, C and D.

Comment: A general rule of software design is:  always favor aggregation over inheritance.  Do you really need D to extend B and C?  Can an instance of D contain a private field of type B and another private field of type C?  Inheritance should not be used just to share methods;  that’s what the word `public` is for.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the java 17 version or later, You can use the sealed interfaces and classes so that you can control which classes that could implement an interface
(for example you can create the interface B and permit only the class A to implement the interface B)

```
public sealed interface B permits A {
  // your code
}
```

than the permited subclass (in this case A) may be declared final to prevent any further extensions.

```
public final class A implements B {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need "real inheritance", simple inheritance is enough if you know what you are doing. Here is simple inheritance mixed with polymorphism and abstraction usage

```
interface Drivable
{ 
public void drive();
}

abstract class User
{
//variables
//Contractor
//Getters Setters
//methods
}

class Driver extends User implements Drivable
{
//variables
//Contractor
//Getters Setters
//methods
//abstract method
}

class Vehicle implements Drivable
{
//variables
//Contractor
//Getters Setters
//methods
//abstract method
}
```

- So each class have relationship with each other on this simple example.
- User is a Driver
- User has a Vehicle
- User can NOT be define more than single driver (extends) but user can have more than single vehicle (implements) or Work Hub (implements).

So, based on your example, if you combined with this concept; A is pointing User() class, B is pointing Driver() class C can point to Customer() class (i did not made that class but it is similar to Driver() class) and D is pointing Drivable() class